# $d^3$ in the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence for (twisted) $KO$

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, k-theory

Cross posted to [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344421/d3-in-the-atiyah-hirzebruch-spectral-sequence-for-twisted-ko) after no response with a bounty.

Let $h^n(-)$ be a generalised cohomology theory.  For a space $X$ there is a spectral sequence known as the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence:

$E_2^{p,q}:=H^p(X;h^q(\ast))\Rightarrow h^{p+q}(X)$.

In the case of complex topological $K$-theory, i.e $KU^n(X)$, the differentials admit nice descriptions in terms of higher cohomology operations (i.e. $d^3=Sq^3$, the Steenrod square of degree $3$).  For twisted $KU$ we have that $d^3(-)=Sq^3(-)+ \lambda\smile (-)$ where $H$ is the class of the twist.

Is there a similar description for real topological (twisted) $K$-theory $KO$?  I am particularly interested in $d^3$.